# Qml: overwritten var type property from c++ side gets invalidated

Tags: c++, qt, qml, var, variant

While playing around with accessing qml properties from c++ side I stumbled upon weird behavior. If property type is `var` and I overwrite property value with different type it gets invalidated when destructor is called.
When one overwrites qml objects property value to i.e. `QVariant(QString())` value gets invalidated when destructor is called.

Example:

I have class `Test` that derives from `QObject` and is registered as qml type. I added `QQmlParserStatus` to get access to `componentComplete()` function.

I create `Test` object in qml and add property `foo`.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Custom 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Test {
        property var foo: 123
    }
}
```

Going to c++ side here is `Test` class source:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlParserStatus>
#include <QMetaProperty>
#include <QDebug>

class Test : public QObject, public QQmlParserStatus
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QObject(parent) {}

    ~Test() {
        const QMetaObject *o = metaObject();
        int offset = o->propertyOffset();
        int count = o->propertyCount();

        for (int i = offset; i < count; ++i) {
            QMetaProperty metaPropert = o->property(i);
            QVariant val = property(metaPropert.name());
            qDebug() << val;
        }
    }

    static void registerTypes() {
        qmlRegisterType<Test>("Custom", 1, 0, "Test");
    }
protected:
    void classBegin() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {}

    void componentComplete() Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
        const QMetaObject *o = metaObject();
        int offset = o->propertyOffset();
        int count = o->propertyCount();

        for (int i = offset; i < count; ++i) {
            QMetaProperty metaPropert = o->property(i);
            QVariant val = property(metaPropert.name());
            qDebug() << val;metaPropert.write(this, QString("test"));
            metaPropert.write(this, QString("test"));
            qDebug() << property(metaPropert.name());
        }
    }
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

In `componentComplete()` I read `foo` property and print it's contents to debug console. Then I overwrite property value with `QVariant(QString("Test))` and print property contents to debug console once again. When turning off application `~Test()` is called where I print `foo` contents to debug console.

And here is the output:

```
QVariant(int, 123)
QVariant(QString, "test")
QVariant(Invalid)
```

What I expected to get:

```
QVariant(int, 123)
QVariant(QString, "test")
QVariant(QString, "test")
```

If property value was string and i overwrite it to string then it doesn't get invalidated.

Also if I change property type from `var` to `variant` property value doesn't get invalidated. But from what I understand `variant` is obsolete and I shouldn't use it.

**My question is**: Why does property gets invalidated? Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: Interesting question. Looks like a bug. Did you created a ticket in Qt bug tracker? Btw, can you try to access a property using `QQmlProperty::read` / `QQmlProperty::write`? Also try `QObject::setProperty` to be sure it works correctly.

Comment: `QQmlProperty::read` / `QQmlProperty::write` no effect and `QObject::setProperty` returned true but didn't fix the problem. I will create a ticket.